# NIS client doesn't automount the home folder

Tags: centos, nfs, nis

I am setting up a computing cluster, and have been tasked with setting up a NIS server and client environment. So far I have been successful on every front except for the NIS clients are not mounting the home directory.

I have been following the steps in [this article](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52668_01/E54669/html/ol7-s13-auth.html), which has gotten me thus far. I am able to login to the NIS client properly, but when it gets there it throws me to a bash prompt and says `Could not chdir to home directory /nethome/cfduser: No such file or directory`. When I get to the bash prompt I can confirm that that `/nethome` directory is there, but it is empty.

I am not sure where to go from here. I can supply whatever configuration files are needed and more if needed.

Both the client and server are running CentOS 7 b1804

Edit 1:

My `/etc/auto.master`

```
# Sample auto.master file
# This is a 'master' automounter map and it has the following format:
# mount-point [map-type[,format]:]map [options]
# For details of the format look at auto.master(5).
#
/misc   /etc/auto.misc
#
# NOTE: mounts done from a hosts map will be mounted with the
#       "nosuid" and "nodev" options unless the "suid" and "dev"
#       options are explicitly given.
#
/net    -hosts
#
# Include /etc/auto.master.d/*.autofs
# The included files must conform to the format of this file.
#
+dir:/etc/auto.master.d
#
# Include central master map if it can be found using
# nsswitch sources.
#
# Note that if there are entries for /net or /misc (as
# above) in the included master map any keys that are the
# same will not be seen as the first read key seen takes
# precedence.
#
+auto.master

/nethome      /etc/auto.home
```

My `/etc/auto.home`

```
* -rw,sync 192.168.1.1:/nethome/&
```

Comment: What's the output of `ypmatch cfduser auto.home`?   Have you checked in the messages log for failed mount attempts?  Can you mount "by hand" successfully (`mount -o rw,sync 192.168.1.1:/nethome/cfduser /mnt/tmp_mnt`)?

Comment: @BowlOfRed I was able to manually mount the folder to the correct location and then I could login with the correct prompt, but it is read only now.

Comment: @BowlOfRed I get this as my result of ypmatch `Can't match key cfduser in map auto.home. Reason: No such key in map`

Comment: @BowlOfRed with the explicit mapping, ypmatch still shows no key match, and the dir still isn't being synced

Comment: @BowlOfRed `ypcat -k auto.master` -> `No such map auto.master. Reason: No such map in server's domain` and `ypcat -k auto.home` -> `cfduser -rw,sync      192.168.1.1:/nethome/cfduser` Does this mean I have a misconfiguration with my auto.master file?

Comment: You have a valid auto.home map.  The line in auto.master looks okay.  I would run autofs in verbose mode and check what messages appear when you try to access.  If you test mount by hand, do it outside of /nethome.  Let that directory belong to automount.

Comment: @BowlOfRed sorry for the late response, but I figured out what the issue was. I forgot to install the `nfs-utils` package for cents so that's why it never mounted.